# Shortening the Hex number by removing leading zeros in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

I have Hex number available in string and I want to shorten it by removing leading zeros. I need to do it in Javascipt.

For example :

All the following numbers are hexadecimal numbers.

```
0000000000000000000000000A000000   -> 00A00000
000000000000000000000000FA000000   -> 000F0A000000

000000000000000000000000C0A80000   -> C0A80000
00000000000000000000003BC0A80000   -> 003BC0A80000
```

The number of digits in the answer should be a multiplication of 4. Like 4 digit answer, 8 digit answer, 12 digit answer, 16 digit answer so on...

My java function is like this.

```
// Remove preciding zero like a hex Eg: 0x0000000000000000000000000A000000 -> 0x0A000000

function hexFormatter(hexToShorted) {
    // make shortHex
    var shortedtHex = hexToShorted.replace(/^(0x)0+(0?.*)$/, "$1$2")
    return shortedtHex;
}
```

Comment: `parseInt(yourString).toString(16).toUpperCase()` will do it

Comment: Cant it result  00003fa like 3fa? I want to get it as 03fa. not 3fa.

Answer (score 2):

You should try yourself first, then post what you did and we can try to help you from there. That said, here is something which could help you out:

```js
let test1 = "0x000000000000000C0045"
test1 = test1.replace(/^(0x)0+((\w{4})+)$/, "$1$2")
console.log(test1)
let test2 = "0x0000000000000000C45"
test2 = test2.replace(/^(0x)0+((\w{4})+)$/, "$1$2")
console.log(test2)
```

I would advise you to [learn regex](https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex), it's extremely useful

Comment: No. the number of digits in the answer should be a multiplication of 4. Like 4 digit answer, 8 digit answer, 12 digit answer, 16 digit answer so on...